# Unable to run localhost in windows

Tags: php, wamp

I want to run php code on my localhost. For the purpose,I just downloaded the wamp server for windows 8 and installed. But when I am trying to open local host , I am directed to the IIS windows. I installed the IIS server earlier and uninstalled it too. Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a port 80 (http) conflict between IIS and WAMP. You should either disable IIS, remove it or change what ports it listens to.